# Provide arguments with a method

Tags: java, arguments

Is there a way in Java to create a method that would **return** the list of **parameters** of **another method** such that I am able to call

```
anotherMethod(method())
```

where `anotherMethod` has arbitrary arguments like

```
public void anotherMethod(int a, int b, String c)
```

And what is if the types stay the same, like with

```
public int add(int a, int b, int c)
```

---

If there is no such way, how could I model the list of parameters such that it would work? Is it a `List` or an **array** or something else?

Comment: Show an actual use-case for what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Varargs

Java has a **built-in** feature to denote a variable length of arguments. It is called **varargs** ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)) (variable arguments) and it only works if the **type stays the same**. The syntax for a method is like this:

```
public int add(int... values)
```

Note the `int... values` which denotes **varargs**. A caller can now call the method like

```
add(null)        // Passing null
add(values)      // Passing an int[]
add()            // No arguments
add(a)           // One int
add(a, b)        // Two ints
add(a, b, c)     // Three ints
add(a, b, c, d)  // Four ints
...
```

Note the three special cases `null`, `int[]` and **empty**.

What Java does is it will convert the arguments into an **array**. So inside the method `values` will be a regular `int[]`. You could thus implement the method like

```
public int add(int... values) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int value : values) {
        sum += value;
    }
    return sum;
}
```

If you, as a caller, want to pass the return value of a `function` you just need to make sure that it returns an **array** like `int[]`. So the following would work:

```
public int[] valueProvider() {
    int[] values = ...

    return values;
}
```

and then call it like

```
int sum = add(valueProvider());
```

---

### Collection, Iterable and Stream

Besides that, if you don't want to use **varargs** or **arrays**, you can use `Collection`s ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html)). A collection may be a `List` or a `Set` and so on. For example you could declare

```
public int add(Collection<Integer> values)
```

and feed it like

```
Collection<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>();
values.add(1);
values.add(2);
int sum = add(values);
```

An `Iterable<Integer>`, in contrast to `Collection<Integer>` would even be more flexible.

Using a `Stream` ([documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)) would also work like a charm and is probably one of the most flexible variants since the source of a stream could be anything and nearly anything of the standard library supports a stream representation.

---

### Changing type

Now note that what you searched for in the beginning, a method that is able to feed arbitrary arguments, is not possible in Java.

The main problem is that the types may change, so you may have a method like

```
public void doSomething(int first, String second, File third)
```

and you won't be able to feed the method with varargs, Collections or any of the presented methods.

In that case you will need a **wrapper class** like

```
public class DoSomethingArguments {
    private int mFirst;
    private String mSecond;
    private File mThird;

    public DoSomethingArguments(int first; String second, File third) {
        this.mFirst = first;
        this.mSecond = second;
        this.mThird = third;
    }

    // Some getters
}
```

(or a generic **tuple** class, a triple in this case)

But then you would need to **change the method** to

```
public void doSomething(DoSomethingArguments arguments)
```

what is probably **not what you wanted** since you probably intended to **not change the signature** of `doSomething`.

But unfortunately there is **no way** to feed a method like this in such a way.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of parameters is fixed at the call site, you could use [varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)

```
int add(int... numbers)
```

otherwise you'd use an array or collection

```
int add(int[] numbers)
```

You can then of course have another method provide the value of these parameters:

```
add(someOtherMethod())
```

Comment: what would be the return type of someOtherMethod() in the present case of int add(int a, int b)?

Comment: For `add(int a, int b)` you need two parameters.There is no way to write it like `add(someOtherMethod())`, because a method can only return a single value. You need to have your method accept an array, collection or varargs (the latter are basically just an array).

Comment: I see, thanks for the reply. One thing more to add, there is a typo in your answer, the varargs is for an arbitrary number of params not a fixed  number.

Comment: I meant to say that the number is fixed (known at compile-time) for each call site, so that you can write `add(a,b,c)` --- for which you need to know that you have three parameters. But each call site can still have a different number than other call sites (i.e. there can also be `add(a,b,c,d)` elsewhere).  If the caller does not know how many parameters there are, you have to pass in an array or a collection.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing that works the way you wish for at **compile** time. As the other answers are pointing out, there are *varargs*. But that is just syntactical sugar. That is just the compiler implicitly creating an array of a certain type for you.

But beyond that, there is **[reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37628/what-is-reflection-and-why-is-it-useful)**. Reflection allows you to dynamically inspect classes and methods at *runtime.

In other words: you can do something like

```
Object whatever = ...
Class<?> someClass = whatever.getClass();
```

And now you can ask `someClass` about the methods it has. And which parameters they need.

But as said: all of that is *runtime* only. And it the reflection APIs are very easy to get wrong. And you only find out at runtime, when some exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

There is not direct way to pass multiple values in the way you want. But you can use a indirect way to pass a group of values of different type. I can think of two ways but their can be more.

Firs - Use a map, just insert the values you want to pass in the collection and pass the collection to the second method.

Second - Create a bean (Java POJO) to pass as parameter to the consuming method.

A small sample code.

```
 class Sample{
    private int a;
    private String b;
    private int c;

    Sample(int a,String b,int c){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.c = c;
    }
    public int getA() {
        return a;
    }
    public void setA(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }
    public String getB() {
        return b;
    }
    public void setB(String b) {
        this.b = b;
    }
    public int getC() {
        return c;
    }
    public void setC(int c) {
        this.c = c;
    }
}
    public class PassingExample {
    public void consumerofInputs (Map<Integer, Object> input)/*(int a, String b, int c)*/{
        System.out.println("I use three different inputs : int, string and int");
        for (Map.Entry<Integer, Object> entry : input.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
        }

    }

    public Map producingInput() {
        Map<Integer, Object> input = new HashMap<Integer, Object>();
        input.put(1, 10);
        input.put(2, "input");
        input.put(3, 89);
        return input;
    }

    public Sample createClassAsInput(){
        Sample input = new Sample(10,"class-input",30);
        return input;

    }

    public void useSampleAsInput(Sample input){
        System.out.println("\nUsing Class as input \nInt::"+input.getA()+"\nString::"+input.getB()+"\nInt::"+input.getC());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PassingExample example = new PassingExample();
        example.consumerofInputs(example.producingInput());
        example.useSampleAsInput(example.createClassAsInput());
    }
}
```